# How to call controller function from template in Django?

Tags: django, templates, methods, controller

How to call controller function from template in Django instead of hardcoding URIs?

Comment: The {% url %} tag does it. Don't know who to credit, because you all answered the same thing.

Comment: You should accept one of them -- ideally, the one whose answer is the easiest to understand.  For what it's worth, Almad answered first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You mean "link to it".

This can be done via `{% url %}` tag, [see docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url)

If Your intent is to call view function directly, this is not possible by design - templates should not know about views, it's a separate layer.

Answer (score 0):

> How to call controller function from template

Not sure what you mean here. If you mean to provide an an HTML link to it see the second part of my answer below.

> instead of hardcoding URIs?

In case you haven't already, use the [`{% url %}` tag](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url). Use this in conjunction with named URLs in your url config.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean adding URL to the resulting HTML, then either use **{% url %}** tag as others, or get used to writing and using [**model_instance.get_absolute_url()**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url). Personally I'm using the latter whenever possible, adding also custom "URL functions" like **get_delete_url()** etc.